# Property in Cache: Request is Not Available in This Context

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, vb.net, iis

I have looked through all of the other "Request is Not Available in This Context" posts on SO and this situation seems unique.

Many of the pages in our application inherit from a "base page" class (we'll call this BP2) which inherits from another "base page" class (we'll call this BP1) which inherits from System.Web.UI.Page. We store many shared functions and web methods in our bottom-level base pages (BP2). I am attempting to access one of these web methods from jQuery and am receiving the error: Request is Not Available in This Context. Accessing the method from code-behind works fine.

This web method is a Public Shared Function in BP2 and the error appears to be coming from a property that the function tries to access from BP1. The property is a list of database results stored in HttpContext.Current.Cache which is populated the first time that it is requested. However, looking at the HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler object shows the property with the value of {"Request is not available in this context."} and it is never populated. The following is a "simplified" version of the code:

BP2:

```
<WebMethod()>
Public Shared Function SaveThing() As Integer
    Return HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler.GetListOfValueId("something")
End Function
```

BP1:

```
Public ReadOnly Property ListOfValues As List(Of lovDbResult)
    Get
        Return Utility.ListOfValues
    End Get
End Property

Public Function GetListOfValueId(ByVal value As String) As Integer
    If value <> "" Then
        'Problem is in the next line.
        For Each lov In HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler.ListOfValues.Where(....)
            Return lov.id
        Next
    End If
    Return New Nullable(Of Integer)
End Function
```

Utility:

```
Public Shared ReadOnly Property ListOfValues() As List(Of lovDbResult)
    Get
        If HttpContext.Current.Cache("ListOfValues") Is Nothing Then
            'Retrieve from database and add to cache.
        End If
        Return HttpContext.Current.Cache("ListOfValues")
    End Get
End Property
```

EDIT: It might be important to note that lovDbResult is a LINQ to SQL result object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was mistaken about where this error was happening, apparently. The property was not being populated because in the section in the psuedo-code above that says "'Retrieve from database and add to cache," there was a call to HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler.Request which *is* unavailable in the context of a WebMethod call. This was corrected by changing this to HttpContext.Current.Request.